# Cant create button increment by one every click

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm trying to build something very simple, every time i click the button it increments the amount inside the html by 1, but it doesn't work and i don't know why:

```js
let increment = document.getElementById("increment")
let counter = document.getElementById("counter")
let count = 0
    
increment.addEventListener("click",adding)
    
function adding() {
    count +=1
    counter.textContent += count
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
       
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="frame">
        <div class="counter">0</div>
        <button id="increment" onclick="adding()"> Click</button>
        <button id="reset"> Reset</button>
    </div>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to override `counter.textContent = count` not `counter.textContent += count`

Comment: You also don't have an element with the id of `counter`. You also don't need to have `onclick="adding()"` as this is added via `addEventListener()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong with your code.

- You need to set `id` of the `div` to `counter` instead of its `class`. As you are retrieving the elements using its `id` in the javascript.
- You are binding the click event of the button twice in your code. Once in HTML with `onclick='adding()'` and a second time in javascript with `increment.addEventListener("click",adding)`, which causes it to increment twice on each click.

```js
let increment = document.getElementById("increment")
let counter = document.getElementById("counter")
let count = 0

function adding() {
    counter.textContent = ++count
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="frame">
        <div id="counter">0</div>
        <button id="increment" onclick="adding()"> Click</button>
        <button id="reset"> Reset</button>
    </div>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to define the selector in you tag: `<div class="counter">0</div>` . Add `id="counter"`
2. Then change `counter.textContent = count++` instead `counter.textContent += count+=1`

```js
let increment = document.getElementById("increment")
let counter = document.getElementById("counter")
let count = 0

increment.addEventListener("click",adding)

function adding() {
    counter.textContent = count
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="frame">
        <div id="counter" class="counter">0</div>
        <button id="increment" onclick="adding()"> Click</button>
        <button id="reset"> Reset</button>
    </div>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. using `onclick` and the `addEventListener` make the function run twice, so the increment is always +2.

**choose only one of the two triggers**

```js
let increment = document.getElementById("increment")
let counter = document.getElementById("counter")
let count = 0

increment.addEventListener("click",adding)

function adding() {
    count +=1
    counter.textContent = count
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="frame">
        <div id="counter" class="counter">0</div>
        <button id="increment"> Click</button>
        <button id="reset"> Reset</button>
    </div>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

See comments in code.

```js
// const is enough
const increment = document.getElementById("increment")
const reset = document.getElementById("reset")
const counter = document.getElementById("counter")
// needs let because count will change
let count = 0

// correcting double adding of click handler
// increment.addEventListener("click",adding)
// but adding it for reset
reset.addEventListener("click",resetCounter)

function adding() {
    count++
    counter.textContent = count // not += 
}

// Added function for reset of counter
function resetCounter () {
    count = 0
    counter.textContent = count
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><!-- Added html start tag -->
<head>        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="frame">
        <div id="counter" class="counter">0</div>
        <button id="increment" onclick="adding()">Click</button>
        <button id="reset"> Reset</button>
    </div>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```